# How to do range query search in Redis on value part of a Key?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

How to do range query based retrieval on value part of Redis?

I am new to Redis. I am planning to use it for caching. I am using StackExchage.Redis library in C#.

for e.g I have entity `Employee`:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId;
    public string Name;
    public float Age;
    public DateTime JoiningDate;
    public DateTime LeavingDate;
    public List<Department> Departments;
    public List<Address> Addresses;
}
```

Where `EmployeeId` is my key and `Employee` object is my value.
I have 1M of such kind of records in my Redis database.

I want to find out certain questions like Range Queries or Sorting by some or combination property of value part (`Employee` object) or if Entity contains another entity (e.g `Employee` contains `Department` and `Department` has its own sort of properties)

1. Get `Employee` whose joining date are between 2017 to 2019?
2. `Employee` who joined 5 years before?
3. While storing record, store in sorted order of some property (don't want to sort in C#)

I am storing data in db using example described here: [Redis for .NET Developer – Redis Hash Datatype](http://taswar.zeytinsoft.com/redis-hash-datatype/)

Comment: Did you consider using the http://redisearch.io module?
Notice the StackExchage.Redis has a built in support for RediSearch.

Comment: @GuyKorland: As i said i am new to redis, so not aware about redisearch.io. Can you point me some links where some ready examples are available for redissearch.io with C# as language?

Comment: See https://www.nuget.org/packages/NRediSearch/
And https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/tree/master/tests/NRediSearch.Test

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use Redis Hash to meet the goal, but you can combine multiple
Redis data structure.

- use hash store all your data(you unavoidable)
- when you sort by Employee date:

  - you can use [Redis Sorted Set](https://redis.io/commands#sorted_set)
  - the Sorted-Set member is your EmployeeId, and the Sorted-Set score is Employee join date
  - you can use ZADD stort your sorted data, and use ZRANGEBYSCORE get you want the sorted result

If you have other sort requirement, you must have convert the sorted property to a number.

Comment: Do you mean when i store value it will be like (key: EmployeeId and Value: SortedSet(Employee object with sorted by Id, JoiningDate and etc...))?

Comment: You should use hash to store your data: key-EmployeeId, value-Employee Object. And then you use sorted set to store sorted by joindate:
- key: SortedJoinDate
- member: EmployeeId
- score: EmployeeJoinDate